# One SSH session one script multiple terminals no X

Tags: ssh, command-line, terminal

I have read other posts asking the same question in the answer was, run your script and have it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e command
```

The problem is that I don't have X installed on that server, so I cannot do neither `gnome-terminal -e command` nor `xterm -e command` nor `konsole -e command`
I hope I have made myself clear on the purpose of what I want and my restriction (no X11)
Does anyone know how to get this ahead?

Comment: You haven't explained what you are trying to do!  If you need multiple terminals over one SSH session, then consider `screen` or `tmux`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need X on the server in order to run `xterm` (or `gnome-terminal`).

If `DISPLAY` is not set once you `ssh` into the server, that might be the problem (check with `echo $DISPLAY`).

If your local machine has no X installed, then you should look at `tmux` or `screen` to "multiply" your terminals.

Comment: Maybe use the -X parameter of ssh too, or do a custom redirection using -R 6010:localhost:6000 and export DISPLAY=localhost:10 if the local X server doesn't do authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Well the most useful solution I have seen for the moment is this one:

```
screen -S CMD1 -d -m command1 ;
screen -S CMD2 -d -m command2 ;
```

And you connect to the screens with: `screen -r <pid>.<cmd>` and logout with `control+a d`
It's interesting but... a bit clunky a would say as you don't visualize your interfaces and have to move from one to another in a not so intuitive way, plus, you have to remember to close them because otherwise you can leave servers running without noticing etc.

If someone think there is a better solution and easy, let me know. ;)
PD: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197395/have-bash-script-execute-multiple-programs-as-separate-processes